# jw player and php dynamic image?

Tags: php, image, jwplayer

I have a php script to show an image once their session is validated. this works fine from a browser, I query the link and it shows up

However I want to use the same image with JW Player and the player does not seem to be able to display the image

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the JW Player [documentation](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/14/skinning-the-jw-player-5), you'll need to make sure the image is in jpg, gif, or png format.  You'll need to make sure you're not providing the image link as a php file when embedding JW Player.  You can do this by using a simple URL rewrite.  In a .htaccess file, you could use this code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^path/to/image.png$ path/to/script.php [L]
```

When embedding it in JW Player, you'll want to set the image as path/to/image.png.